# How to connect to SQL server integration service from asp.net web serivce

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ssis

I have an asp.net web service that needs to connect to SSIS, so far i couldn't find a clear way of connecting to the SSIS and getting table data, how can i do this? you can point me in the right direction by giving me a link to a site that explains it indepth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below urls will help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28096/Excecute-SSIS-package-DTSX-from-ASP-Net

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic755428-364-1.aspx